# .contentShape losing effect when overlayed

Tags: swiftui

I'm finding .contentShape isn't working the same when it is on top of other shapes that also accept gesture interactions.

Take the following example code:

```
ZStack {
//    Circle()
//        .offset(y: -200)
//        .gesture(TapGesture().onEnded { print("TAPPED CIRCLE") } )
    
    let path = Path() { path in
        path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 1000))
    }
    
    path
        .stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
        .contentShape(path.stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10)))
        .gesture(TapGesture().onEnded { print("TAPPED PATH") })
}
```

With this code, as is, the contentShape on the path will make taps recognized from a significant distance.

Uncommenting the code for the Circle, suddenly the contentShape doesn't have the same effect and now taps need to be exactly on the path for them to work.

Why is this happening? Can I somehow get the same behaviour even when the "Circle code" is present?

Comment: Conflict of gesture recognisers (offset does not change location of view frame which handles touches).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an extra little bit of debugging and realized it was working fine. The behaviour *is* different, though, depending on whether the circle is behind or not.

Here is my extra "debugging":

```
ZStack {
    Circle()
        .offset(y: -200)
        .gesture(TapGesture().onEnded { print("TAPPED CIRCLE") } )
    
    let path = Path() { path in
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 1000))
    }
    
    path
        .stroke(Color.green, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 40))
    
    path
        .stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
        .contentShape(path.stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 40)))
        .gesture(TapGesture().onEnded { print("TAPPED PATH") })
}
```

All this is doing is adding an extra path, drawing with a stroke the same lineWidth as the contentShape so I can see where the clicks are changing from registering and not registering on the path.

Where the path is over the circle, the hit detection is actually *better* than where it is not.

It seems that when there isn't a shape underneath, also accepting gesture interaction, there is an additional buffer to where the gestures are recognized.

Losing the buffer, and hence changing the behaviour, is what was making me think there was a problem.